# RegisterAttribute duplication error in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I’m facing this issue from a Xamarin.iOS project that i’m trying to maintain, anytime I modify a XIB file all the designer.cs files get regenerated but I end up with this error. it seems that Registering the viewcontroller class partially clashes with the generated designer file. are you guys aware of any material for me to look up?

`` Error CS0579: The attribute `Foundation.RegisterAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times (CS0579) ``

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but this error happened to me right now. Probably if you encounter this error, you are using a partial class and the generated part already has this attribute. So, just remove it.

Comment: Since [Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a forum](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107), there is no need to include disclaimers about the age of the post or similar. We [encourage answers even on older questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/118563/269535).

Comment: Thanks dude..i encouraged it recently..This helps